# How and Why did the Matador fly?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Fredo the Matador went out for his last perfomance and he wanted to make it spectacular.

Andre the Bull was the most dangerous of all.

Before he entered the arena he turned to his disciple. 'If I die today I, please let this beast know that the Matador forgives him'

His wife exclaims as he enters the arena 'I love you!'

Then the animal charged him to a corner. It seemed certain death. But then a metamorphosis occured and with a few swings the Matador flew in the air dazzling the crowd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it... That he drank red bull before entering the arena? If you look at each statement you can find the phrase 'Red Bull gives you wings'. fREDo, BULL, forGIVES, YOU, sWINGS.